# Barycenter of a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry

Given a tetrahedron whose vertices are represented as vectors $v_A,v_B,v_C,v_D$, I have the following questions:

1) How to represent its `barycenter` $v_E$?

2) Are the distances from the barycenter $v_E$ to its four faces the same? Why?

3) For a face, saying $ABC$, if we represent its center as $v_E^{ABC} = \frac{1}{3}(v_A+v_B+v_C)$, and the vector from $v_E^{ABC}$ to $v_E$ is $\vec{p}$, is $\vec{p}$ perpendicular to the face $ABC$?

4) If I want a scalar to evaluate how is a tetrahedron stretched, how to do it? (Suppose the stretched extent of an equilateral tetrahedron is zero; for a fully degenerated tetrahedron, the stretched extent is infinity).

Comment: Is the tetrahedron regular?

Comment: Not sure, I mean here the tetrahedron is just general.

Comment: In (4), maybe you are looking for a measure of the "aspect ratio" of a tetrahedron. [There are several slightly different measures used in practice.](https://www.google.com/search?q=aspect+ratio+tetrahedron)

Answer (score 1):

1. $v_E = {1 \over 4} (v_A + v_B + v_C + v_D )$.
2. No. Take the Tetrahedron $T_x = \operatorname{co} \{ 0, e_1, e_2, x e_3 \} $. The barycentre is ${1 \over 4} (1, 1,x)^T$ which
   approaches ${1 \over 4} (1, 1,0)^T$. The distance to the 'top' and 'bottom' faces goes to zero, whereas the distance to the 'side' faces goes to ${1 \over 4}$.
3. No. Let $T_v = \operatorname{co} \{ 0, e_1, e_2, v \}$, with $[v]_3 >0$. Then the 'lower' face is fixed, regardless of $v$, and so is the perpendicular in the question. However, the barcenter 'moves' around as we vary $v$ hence the perpendicular does not pass through the barycentre in general.
4. I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, maybe try ${1 \over \det \begin{bmatrix} v_B-v_A & v_C-v_A & v_D-v_A\end{bmatrix}} -1$